# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while using onclick event

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I am facing a problem while using the onclick event
Can you please help me?

```
movie1.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${IMG_URL + poster_path}" alt="Poster">
                <p class="title">${title}</p>
                <span>Rating : ${vote_average}</span>
                <div class="summary">
                    <p>${overview}</p>
                </div>
              <button class="watchbtn" onclick="passname(${title})" >Watch</button>
            </div>
        `;
```

In the Above code I get an error which shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: the error seems not to be in this code snippet, can you share a little bit more code?

Comment: What is in the `title` variable?

Comment: @LasseLenting the error occurs when I pass the $(title) parameter in the onclick event

Comment: @NickParsons  there's a string

Comment: can you be more exact? what does the string look like?

Comment: @ManavJoshi what is it's contents? It should be: `passname('${title}')`

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks a lot, the error has been resolved, Thanks a bunchhhh

Comment: @NickParsons btw I was fetching the title through an Api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
movie1.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${IMG_URL + poster_path}" alt="Poster">
                <p class="title">${title}</p>
                <span>Rating : ${vote_average}</span>
                <div class="summary">
                    <p>${overview}</p>
                </div>
              <button class="watchbtn" onclick="passname('${title}')" >Watch</button>
            </div>
        `;
```